# найти количество повторяющихся элементов в массиве

Tags: javascript

найти количество повторяющихся элементов в массиве  (ответ 8)

вот наброски

```
<script>
a=[1,11,13,121,13,11,11,11,7,9,9]

n=a.length
cnt=0;
for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
    flag=true; 
for(j=i+1;j<n;j++){
   if((a[i]==a[j])&&(i==j))
       flag=false;
}
if(flag){cnt++};
}  
console.log(cnt)

</script>
```

если можно,то поправьте мои записи

Comment: Нужно найти общее количество или количество одного максимально повторяющегося элемента? Какой правильный ответ в вашем примере?

Comment: @KromStern, ответ же 8, значит надо количество всех неуникальных элементов в массиве.

Comment: @Qwertiy считать так (11,13,13,11,11,11,9,9) итого 8

Comment: cheburashkarf, я так и посчитал. Это для @KromStern был ответ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Классический способ

```
function calc(a) {
  var count={}, res=0, q;

  for (q=0; q<a.length; ++q) {
    count[a[q]] = ~~count[a[q]] + 1;
  }

  for (q in count) {
    if (count.hasOwnProperty(q) && count[q] > 1) {
      res += count[q];
    }
  }

  return res;
}

calc([1,11,13,121,13,11,11,11,7,9,9]) // 8
```

## ES6

```
function calc(a) {
  let count = Object.create(null);

  for (let x of a) {
    count[x] = ~~count[x] + 1;
  }

  return a.length - Object.keys(count).filter(x => count[x]>1).length;
}

calc([1,11,13,121,13,11,11,11,7,9,9]) // 8
```

PS: Допускаю, что на ES6 можно ещё что-то переписать.

Comment: Простите,а как эту дичь ~~count[a[q]] + 1; можно попонятнее переписать?

Comment: вообще это работает как округление в меньшую сторону, но причем оно тут?

Comment: По другому эту строку можно представить так: _count[a[q]] = a[q] in count ? count[a[q]] + 1 : 1;_

Comment: @vihtor, это принудительный каст в int32. В том числе превращает undefined, NaN и всякий мусор в 0. Твой вариант замены в принципе верный. Если никто в прототип Object'а не напихает числовых ключей. Впрочем, если там окажутся числовые ключи с числовыми значениями, то мой тоже не поможет. Но это ситуация вообще из области фантастики.

Comment: @cheburashkarf, `if (count[a[q]]) { count[a[q]] = 1; } else { ++count[a[q]]; }`. C теми же недостатками, что перечислены выше.

Answer (score 2):

У меня так получилось

```
function countDoubles(list) {

  var items = list.slice(0),  // клонируем исходный массив
      tested = [],            // список проверенных элементов
      item,                   // один элемент
      count = 0;              // кол-во элементов, имеющх дубли

  while (items.length) {
    // вырезаем первый элемент (что бы он нам больше не попадался)
    item = items.shift();
    // если его еще не проверяли
    if (tested.indexOf(item) === -1) {
      // добавляем в список
      tested.push(item);
      // и ищем дубли
      if (items.indexOf(item) >= 0) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}

countDoubles([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0]) // 4
countDoubles([1,11,13,121,13,11,11,11,7,9,9]) // 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая классная библиотека linqjs.

```
Enumerable.From([1,11,13,121,13,11,11,11,7,9,9]).Distinct().ToArray()
```

Вернет уникальные знания.

Кроме этого есть куча других полезности.
Ссылка http://neue.cc/reference.htm

---

lodash/underscore

```
_.uniq([1,11,13,121,13,11,11,11,7,9,9])
```

Получаешь уникальные значения.
Также очень много плюшек, такие как проверка, работа с массивами.

Если ты не уверен в своих знаниях, используй фреймворки, там уже за тебя все сделали.

Удачи!

Comment: Причем тут список уникальных элементов? В условии сказано: **кол-во повторяющихся элементов**

Comment: ах, да точно :) 
Я что то не дочитал) Ссори.

Comment: Тогда в момем примере будет так
'Enumerable.From([1,11,13,121,13,11,11,11,7,9,9]).Distinct().Count()'
-----------
_.uniq([1,11,13,121,13,11,11,11,7,9,9]).length

Comment: ну так это вы снова выбираете список уникальных элементов. но по такому списку нельзя сказать какие его элементы повторялись. например: [1,2, 3, 3] в вашем решении результат будет 3 (три уникальных элемента), но повторяется только один из них, по этому правильный ответ будет 1

Comment: А ну тогда вот
var source = [1,11,13,121,13,11,11,11,7,9,9]
var uniq = Enumerable.From(source).Distinct().Count()
var count = source.length - uniq;

Comment: попробуйте сначала проверить то, что предлагаете. что даст разница в кол-ве элементов и кол-ве уникальных элементов? в примере с таким массивом _[1,2,3,3,3,3]_ вы  вычтете 3 из 6 и снова получите ответ 3, хотя правильный ответ 1

Comment: @vihtor, нет, правильный ответ в твоём примере именно 3. Нужно общее количество неуникальных элементов. Оно равно количеству всех минус количество уникальных.

Comment: В связи с последними правками условий задания, да все поменялось

Comment: Хотя нет, в условии сказано что правильный ответ 8, а это значит что учитываются не только повторения но и первое число. По этому в моём примере правильный ответ будет 4, т.к. [1,2,**3**,**3**,**3**,**3**]

Answer (score 0):

если у тебя 2 массива, то можно так попробовать:

```
function matchArrays(v, r){
    var count = [];
    for (var i =0; i<v.length; i++){
        for(var j =0; j<r.length; j++){
            if (v[i] === r[j]){
            count.push(v[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return count.length;
}
matchArrays([1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,6]); /* 4 (количество повторений одного элемента в 
двух массивах)*/
```